# How R differentiates between the two filter function one in dplyr package and other for linear filtering in time series?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, time-series

I wanted to filter a data set based on some conditions. When I looked at the help for filter function the result was:

```
filter {stats}  R Documentation
Linear Filtering on a Time Series
Description
Applies linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each series separately of a multivariate time series.
```

After searching on web I found the filter function I needed i.e. from dplyr package. How can R have two functions with same name. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment the R interpreter would dispatch a call to `filter` to the `dplyr` environment, at least if the class of the object were among the avaialble methods:

methods(filter)
[1] filter.data.frame* filter.default*    filter.sf*         filter.tbl_cube*   filter.tbl_df*     filter.tbl_lazy*
[7] filter.ts*

As you can see there is a `ts` method, so if the object were of that class, the interpreter would instead deliver the x values to it. However, it appears that the authors of `dplyr` have blocked that mechanism and instead put in a warning function. You would need to use:

```
getFromNamespace('filter', 'stats')
function (x, filter, method = c("convolution", "recursive"), 
    sides = 2L, circular = FALSE, init = NULL) 
{  <omitting rest of function body> }

# same result also obtained with:
stats::filter
```

R functions are contained in namespaces, so a full designation of a function would be: `namespace_name::function_name`. There is a hierarchy of namespace containers (actually "environments" in R terminology) arranged along a search path (which will vary depending on the order in which packages and their dependencies have been loaded). The `::`-infix-operator can be used to specify a namespace or package name that is further up the search path than might be found in the context of the calling function. The function `search` can display the names of currently loaded packages and their associated namespaces. See `?search` Here's mine at the moment (which is a rather bloated one because I answer a lot of questions and don't usually start with a clean systems:

```
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"                "package:kernlab"           "package:mice"              "package:plotrix"          
 [5] "package:survey"            "package:Matrix"            "package:grid"              "package:DHARMa"           
 [9] "package:eha"               "train"                     "package:SPARQL"            "package:RCurl"            
[13] "package:XML"               "package:rnaturalearthdata" "package:rnaturalearth"     "package:sf"               
[17] "package:plotly"            "package:rms"               "package:SparseM"           "package:Hmisc"            
[21] "package:Formula"           "package:survival"          "package:lattice"           "package:remotes"          
[25] "package:forcats"           "package:stringr"           "package:dplyr"             "package:purrr"            
[29] "package:readr"             "package:tidyr"             "package:tibble"            "package:ggplot2"          
[33] "package:tidyverse"         "tools:rstudio"             "package:stats"             "package:graphics"         
[37] "package:grDevices"         "package:utils"             "package:datasets"          "package:methods"          
[41] "Autoloads"
```

At the moment I can find instances of 3 versions of filter using the help system:

```
?filter

# brings this up in the help panel

Help on topic 'filter' was found in the following packages:

Return rows with matching conditions
(in package dplyr in library /home/david/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5.1)
Linear Filtering on a Time Series
(in package stats in library /usr/lib/R/library)
Objects exported from other packages
(in package plotly in library /home/david/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5.1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will be looking at it for better understanding.